# URL encoding issue: Spaces encoded as plus signs instead of %20 in OData query

Tags: javascript, pact

I'm facing an issue with URL encoding in an OData query. When I encode spaces in the query, the software seems to be representing them as plus signs (`+`) instead of the standard `%20`.

Encoded URL (from user input):

```
$select=ID&$expand=Apps($select=ID,Type;$filter=Target/any(d:(d%20eq%20'PC'))))))))
```

Parsed URL (result):

```
$select=ID&$expand=Apps($select=ID,Type;$filter=Target/any(d:(d+eq+'PC'))))))))
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, how did you address it? Is there a specific setting or configuration that controls the URL encoding behavior in [Pact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pact-foundation/pact)?

I've considered aligning the encoding with the standard URL encoding convention (`%20`) for compatibility. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `+` is the correct encoding for a space, eg. `Hello there` encoded is `Hello+there`.. What problem are you actually having with the `+`?

Comment: It would help if you could please share how you are putting these into your Pact test, and ideally, a repository we can clone that shows the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Keith I am using it to test an Odata server, "+" is not acceptable, we use %20 instead.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear what problem your asking, a `+` is the standard for URL encoding a space.   eg.  Even say in google search, try searching `hello there` and look at what the url says.  You say -> `the software`,  what software is this?.   And `Parsed URL (result):`,  parsed from what exactly.